# How to copy tables plus data for testing purposes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, testing, export

How can I copy a number of tables, plus the data they contain, from a live SQL Server database?

I want to get some data for basic testing on my machine.

I was originally going to do a simple backup of the database, until I noticed that it was over 100GB in size. However the tables I'm after are only a number of the smaller ones. I then tried export to Excel, but hit the 65K limit *(and we don't have Excel 2007)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Exporting Data by Using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
[Here is MSDN video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952922.aspx)

you can export it as Flat file

In Management Studio, select the database, right-click and select **Tasks->Export Data.** There you will see options to export to different kinds of formats including **CSV**.

You can also run your query from the Query window and save the results to CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, however the video is for exporting to Excel, but at least for the Excel 2003 we have, it's limited to 65k records

Comment: That got me going ... solution I went with was using the Export Data and setting the Destination as a new database in my local SQL Express instance

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the Export Data wizard from your live server to your testing machine? Or use [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)? Or even use a simple PowerShell script?

```
$Server = "MyServer"
$ServerInstance = "$Server\MyInstance"
$database = "MyDatabase"
$BackupFile = "c:\MyBackupFile.sql"

$tables = @('TableBlah','TableBluh','TableBloh')

$server = New-Object (
  'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $ServerInstance
$scripter = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') $server

$scripter.Options.SchemaQualify = $false
$scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = $false
$scripter.Options.ScriptData = $true
$scripter.Options.NoCommandTerminator = $true
$scripter.Options.ToFileOnly = $true
$scripter.Options.FileName = $BackupFile
$ServerUrn=$server.Urn 

$UrnsToScript = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.UrnCollection

foreach ($t in $tables)
{ 
  # Could use bcp here for dumping big tables (like archives)
  # $ret = (bcp.exe "$database..$t" out `"$ConfigBackupDir\$t.bcp`" 
  #   -S $ServerInstance -U sa -P $SAPWD -n) 

  $Urn = "$ServerUrn/Database[@Name='" + 
    $database + "']/Table[@Name='" + $t + "' and @Schema='dbo']"
  $UrnsToScript.Add($Urn)
}

$scripter.EnumScript($UrnsToScript)
```

Comment: Sorry, very new to SQL export, so no idea what's available, never mind what's the better option ... my experiments with export to Excel weren't very successful. Thanks for the pointers